# I have a problem with plugin revolution slider

Tags: wordpress, plugins, slider

My website has been working well for over a year. But no longer works. Because of the revolution slider plugin. When I delete it, the site returns to work.
This message appears to me in the error file "error_log".

---

```
[18-May-2019 10:35:11 UTC] خطأ Unknown column 'type' in 'where clause' في قاعدة بيانات ووردبريس  للاستعلام select * from wpyb_revslider_sliders where `type` != 'template' order by id ASC القادم من require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/traveltour/page.php'), get_footer, locate_template, load_template, require_once('/themes/traveltour/footer.php'), wp_footer, do_action('wp_footer'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, wp_admin_bar_render, do_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, RevSliderFront::add_admin_menu_nodes, RevSliderSlider->getAllSliderForAdminMenu, RevSliderSlider->getArrSliders, RevSliderDB->fetch [18-May-2019 10:35:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'fetch - <b>Unknown column 'type' in 'where clause'</b><br>---<br> Query: select * from wpyb_revslider_sliders where `type` != 'template' order by id ASC' in /home/......../public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions.class.php:14 Stack trace:
#0 /home/........./public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/db.class.php(26): RevSliderFunctions::throwError('fetch - <b>Unkn...', -1)
#1 /home/......./public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/db.class.php(41): RevSliderDB->throwError('fetch - <b>Unkn...')
#2 /home/......../public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/db.class.php(132): RevSliderDB->checkForErrors('fetch')
#3 /home/....../public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/slider.class.php(2408): RevSliderDB->fetch('wpyb_revslider_...', '`type` != 'temp...', 'id', '', 'ASC')
#4 /home/....../public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/slider.class.php(2 in /home/......../public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions.class.php on line 14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uninstall it and reinstall it , which version of wordpress and rev slider you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

I have updated Wordpress. 
The problem was solved.
Thanks a lot